# angular2-Highcharts not working in angular-cli project

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have created a new project using angular-cli
I followed all the steps that are suggested at the page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts

npm install angular2-highcharts --save
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')

When I run the app, it says cannot find name 'require'
Do I need to follow any other steps.

Comment: You can a live example with the config of angular2 with highcharts http://embed.plnkr.co/IuwjpPB1YQW1T7i4B8SZ/

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Using system.config works fine (like in the example @morganfree linked to) but the second you try to aot compile with angular cli poop hits the fan and you can't execute a rollup.

Comment: You can try following workaround for making it work for AOT rollup build https://davidsekar.com/angularjs/workaround-for-using-angular2-highcharts-with-aot-rollup-build

Answer (score 1):

**Try to add this dclaration on your component : declare var require: any;**

I had the same problem.
I didn't have much time to resolve the problem. So i used **ng2-highchart** (an alternative for angular2-highcharts).

-you can follow [instruction for installation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-highcharts) by there

-You will find the github project for more informations.

-With an [example on Angular-Cli](https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts/wiki/Angular-Cli-Usage) .

Comment: This worked somewhat but not working for angular 8